# How to resize product images without the magento resize commands

Tags: magento2, product-images, catalog, image-resize

We have magento setup with magento version 2.3.5-p2. Currently it is showing broken product images. After running the resize command **bin/magento catalog:images:resize**, product images are working fine.

Is there any way to resize images automatically without running the command manually?

Comment: Clear the image cache. If you don't run the resize command, Magento will resize that on the fly. Check view.xml under theme etc directory where you can found the image size

Comment: Already tried serveral time. It is not working.

Answer (score 0):

you can run this resize commands automatically by keeping cron for a specific period of time as per your need. In this way, you don't want to run commands manually each time